# Using Powershell and Windows forms. Is there a way to get key input with out a textbox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am using Powershell and Windows forms. Is there a way to get key input **without** a textbox?

For a Textbox I know you could do the follow.

```
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$newid=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})  #VARIABLE CAPTURE
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell provides Read-Host, which will read from the powershell prompt.

`$newid = Read-Host`

Comment: ..but this has nothing to do with a Windows Form

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are trying to create a form with no controls at all or where typing a key returns a specific value before the focused control receives the key pressed?

In that case I would scope the variable that receives the input to have at least the `script` scope like this: `$script:FormResult`

As demo a small form that has no other controls, just a label that shows some actions the user can choose from by pressing a key

```
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text = "Select option"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
# with this, the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.
$objForm.KeyPreview = $true

$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$Label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Text = @"
Select an action to perform.

1. Perform action 1
2. Perform action 2
3. Perform action 3

Press Escape to cancel
Press Enter to perform all actions
"@

$objForm.Controls.Add($Label)

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({
    $script:FormResult = $null
    switch ($_.KeyCode) {
        {'Enter','Return' -contains $_} { $script:FormResult = 'AllActions' ; break }
        {'D1', 'NumPad1' -contains $_}  { $script:FormResult = 'Action1'; break }
        {'D2', 'NumPad2' -contains $_}  { $script:FormResult = 'Action2'; break }
        {'D3', 'NumPad3' -contains $_}  { $script:FormResult = 'Action3'; break }
        'Escape'                        { $script:FormResult = 'Cancel' }
    }
    if ($script:FormResult) { $objForm.Close() }
})

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

# clean up the form from memory when done
$objForm.Dispose()
```

After this, you can check whatever the user chose using variable `$script:FormResult`

Hope that helps